# Javascript code is executed twice after using it three times

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am trying to make a javascript command that creates dropdowns successively. However, if I change a dropdown, the child dropdown should dissapear. This is the javascript:

```
var categorycount = 0;

function categorygenerate() {

    //for testing purposes
        var categoryarray = new Array(), i;
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            categoryarray[i] = Math.random();
        }
        return categoryarray;
    }
    function delete_category(selectedcategory){
        restar = categorycount - selectedcategory;
        categoria = "category" + restar;
        var element = document.getElementById(categoria);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        categorycount = restar;
    }

function dropdowngenerate(divname) {
    comparelevel = divname.slice(-1);
    if (comparelevel != categorycount){
        delete_category(comparelevel)
    }
    else{
    ++categorycount;
    var categoria = "category" + categorycount;
    var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<select>', categories = categorygenerate(), i;
    for(i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        html += "<option value='"+categories[i]+"'>"+categories[i]+"</option>";
    }
    html += '</select>';
    newDiv.innerHTML= html;
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.setAttribute("id",categoria);
    newDiv.setAttribute('onchange', "dropdowngenerate('"+categoria+"');");
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="category0">
<select onchange="dropdowngenerate('category0');">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>
```

The script works well the first 3 times, but in the fourth dropdown, the script is called twice. The first time it's called, it works properly. The second time, it is executed as if the second dropdown (category1) had been changed and deletes the rest of the dropdowns.

Any clue?

Comment: Maybe your onchange event is getting created more than once and being called twice after a while.

Comment: You didn't post the code for the categorygenerate() function.  maybe the problem is there

Comment: You can edit your question to make a working code example (using "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You are also missing a closing curly brace at the end of dropdowngenerate

Comment: Fixed those in the post, however they are not errors in the code.

Comment: As @Igor suggests, a working example would be very helpful to actually see the problem occurring.

Comment: Don't set JavaScript with setAttribute. Use addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**:

This code will look for an existing sibling that is a container for nested children.  If it finds one it removes it.  Then a new such container is created with the event handler attached.

```js
document.getElementById("selectCategory_0").addEventListener("change", handle_onChange);

function handle_onChange(event){
  var parentContainer = this.parentNode;

  // ---------------------------
  // if a child dropdown exist, remove it
  // ---------------------------
  var childContainer = parentContainer.querySelector(".selectContainer");
  if (childContainer) { parentContainer.removeChild(childContainer); }
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // create a new child dropdown
  // ---------------------------
  var categories = categorygenerate();
  childContainer = generateChild(document, categories);
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // add the new childContainer to the DOM "after" the current dropdown
  // ---------------------------
  parentContainer.insertBefore(childContainer, this.nextSibling);
  // ---------------------------
}

function generateChild(root, categories){
  // ---------------------------
  // build an html string
  // ---------------------------
  var html = "<div class='selectContainer'><select>";
  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    html += "<option value='" + categories[i] + "'>" + categories[i] + "</option>";
  }
  html += '</select></div>';
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // create an element from the html string
  // ---------------------------
  var tplt = root.createElement('template');
  tplt.innerHTML = html;
  var el = tplt.content.firstChild;
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // attach the change handler
  // ---------------------------
  el.firstChild.addEventListener("change", handle_onChange);
  // ---------------------------
  
  return el;
}

function categorygenerate() {
  var categoryarray = new Array()

  // ---------------------------
  // for testing purposes
  // ---------------------------
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    categoryarray[i] = Math.random();
  }
  // ---------------------------

  return categoryarray;
}
```

```css
.selectContainer { padding: 1em;}
```

```html
<div id="category0" class="selectContainer">
  <select id="selectCategory_0">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to generate a dropdown each time I change a dropdown, but if I choose a previously selected dropdown, the following dropdowns must be deleted.

Comment: So, if a user changes a "secondary" dropdown, a new tertiary dropdown should be created?  Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, and if the third one is selected, a fourth should be created. However, if the second is selected again, the third and the fourth should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your code, a simple way to do this, is using a function like

```
("#category0").lastChild.remove()
```

That'll delete the last child (which is category1) and also the child of this one. I don't truely understand your thinking but I hope that'll help. :P